# Вставка в vim (linux mint)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, vim

Такая проблема:
Пишу в vime, в каком-то определенном месте мне нужно произвести вставку текста, который был мною скопирован из браузера. При этом, когда пытаюсь осуществить вставку с помощью мыши - vim никак не реагирует. Если пытаюсь вставить с помощью 'p' то вставляется последний удаленный/скопированный элемент в vim. Как осуществить подобную вставку?

Comment: Переход в режим ввода в vim осуществляется после нажатия клавиши "i" (в vi после нажатия "a"), вставка мышью может осуществляться как с помощью правой, так и с помощью средней (колесо) клавиши. Советую более исчерпывающе описать что вы делали, чтобы участники смогли обнаружить проблему не тратя время на расспросы.

Comment: i и a работают и в vi, и в vim. У них чуточку разное поведение (курсор вставляется по разные стороны от текущего символа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при "вставке мышей" вим находится в командном режиме, то, может и ничего и не произойти. А может "попортить текст". Переведите вначале в режим редактирования <kbd>i</kbd> и потом пробуйте вставить. Правда при этом текст скорее всего будет "страшно переформатирован" - вим воспринимает вставку буквально, как будто нажимали кнопки. Поэтому, перед вставкой лучше перейти в специальный режим вставки

```
:set paste
```

а после вставки вернуть назад

```
:set nopaste
```

Конечно, может такое быть, что вим собран с отключенной поддержкой буфера обмена и мыши, но это вряд ли. Но если все нормально, то есть более простые способы

Вставка с обычного буфера обмена  <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, вставка с буфера выделения (когда просто мышей выделяем, но ничего не копируем) Вставка с обычного буфера обмена  <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: Нет, не работают: вставка выполняется не из буфера выделения или обмена, а из буфера vim

Comment: Показывайте вывод vim -version. Наверно криво собран. Или терминал кривой

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Garbage after option argument: "-version"
More info with: "vim -h"
Vim с дефолтного репозитория, пользуюсь им давно. Так что вряд ли там что-то криво собрано.

Comment: Там два минуса а не один. Я проверил на первом попавшем минте и там собрано без поддержки буфера обмена.

Comment: тобишь подобная вставка не возможна?

Comment: Я не разобрался до конца, но должны быть включены фичи +xterm_clipboard и +clipboard (и наверное +mouse* для полного счастья). 
Проверил  у себя. (gentoo+xfce+xfce-terminal). консольный вим нормально работает (фичи включены). Но при ssh на убунту-сервер уже не работает. В xterm такая же ситуация. 
Может попробовать gvim?